# How do I create a log-file for JNativeHook data?

Tags: java, jnativehook

So I downloaded JNativeHook (https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) but it only captures data for a short period of time before overwriting itself.

I'm a complete beginner here, but what I'm *trying* to do is collect all my mouse and keyboard data, log it somewhere, then take that data and input it into a data visualizer so I can visually track my activity.

Would anyone be able to help me get started? Or a solid path to achieve this? I've got NativeHook working but having difficulties piecing everything else together.

If it matters, I'm working off of the newer model Macbook Pro.

Comment: Where does it store the captured data? Can you post some code you use?

Comment: I downloaded it from this page: https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases

And at the moment, it doesn't store the data anywhere. The 'JNativeHookDemo' window opens and the data is shown as a live stream in the window. The issue is that as new data is created, the old data is deleted.

Since I am trying to track the data over the course of a day, I need to figure out how to store it somewhere.